# How to set Permission based on roles for Views Data Export

Tags: 7, views, users, importing-exporting

Using [views data export module](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export), I set the permission for different roles in the **Data Export** in Views like:

[image]

But I can still see the Export button for all users in front page. However if the role doesn't have permission to export then after clicking it they are redirected to ***Access Denied Page***

Is there any way I can ***hide*** the export button from all the user roles except the ones that have permission to export?

If it was a link defined in ***.tpl.php** then I could have done something like

```
<?php if (in_array('myRole', $user->roles)): ?>
// The export button
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I couldn't figure out how to do it with Views Data Export *(without hacking the module)*

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the 7.x-3.0-beta8 version. See the issue thread [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1985960).

Answer (score -1):

Add a template for the view. Then by using css, hide the default export button coming with view. Then print the export link manually based on user role.